# How can I get the Infobox from a Wikipedia article by the MediaWiki API?

Tags: wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Wikipedia articles may have Infobox templates. By the following call I can get the first section of an article which includes an Infobox.

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&pageid=568801&section=0&prop=wikitext
```

I want a query which will return only Infobox data. Is this possible?

Comment: See [How to extract information from a Wikipedia infobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862336/how-to-extract-information-from-a-wikipedia-infobox) for a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 38):

You can do it with a URL call to the Wikipedia API like this:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xmlfm&titles=Scary%20Monsters%20and%20Nice%20Sprites&rvsection=0
```

Replace the `titles=` section with your page title, and `format=xmlfm` to `format=json` if you want the article in JSON format.

Answer (score 17):

Instead of parsing infoboxes yourself, which is quite complicated, take a look at [DBPedia](https://wiki.dbpedia.org/about), which has Wikipedia infoboxes extracted out as database objects.

Comment: This, however, will give you all the relationships to a particular entity but won't tell you which fields exist in the infobox

Comment: IIUIC they don't provide any databases via API, only some extraction tools. So you need to fetch everything locally.

Answer (score 5):

Building on [garry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638402/how-can-i-get-the-infobox-from-a-wikipedia-article-by-the-mediawiki-api/13848631#13848631), you can have Wikipedia parse the info box into HTML for you via the `rvparse` parameter like so:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=Scary%20Monsters%20and%20Nice%20Sprites&rvsection=0&rvparse
```

Note that neither method will return *just* the info box. But from the HTML content, you can extract (via, e.g., [Beautiful Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup)) the `table` with class `infobox`.

In [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), you do something like the following

```
resp = requests.get(url).json()
page_one = next(iter(resp['query']['pages'].values()))
revisions = page_one.get('revisions', [])
html = next(iter(revisions[0].values()))
# Now parse the HTML
```

Answer (score 4):

If the page has a right side infobox, then use this URL to obtain it in txt form.

My example is using the element [hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen). All you need to do is replace "Hydrogen" with your title.

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?action=raw&title=Template:Infobox%20hydrogen

If you are looking for JSON format use this URL, but it's not pretty.

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Template:Infobox%20hydrogen&format=json

Comment: I think this works because this page exists:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_hydrogen .
Replacing hydrogen alone with, let's say, "summer" doesn't work