# How do I use the Wikipedia API

Tags: php, api

I want try to get tennis players description from wikipedia without scratch the DOM page on a player x. It's not allowed and very boring. So, I hope someone can reply to my only question.

What can I do precisly with the Wikipedia API ? Can I get informations about a collection of tennis players easily ? or this API is not working for this. If not, I need someone tells me what is the purpose of this API because I don't understand the documentation.

Comment: I heard they are working on a new db system where basic information about people, towns, etc is stored in a language-neutral way. I guess these kind of queries going to be a easier in the future...

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1338245/necko?tab=questions) is solved. By awarding good answers you make stackoverflow work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Wikipedia API Sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aApiSandbox) - with that you can play around and try to get the info you need.

To get the info from a page, you can use the *parse* action.

Trying to get the information for the danish tennisplayer Caroline Wozniacki, I used the *parse* action along with the *json* format.
In the field labeled **page** I pasted `Caroline_Wozniacki` and I pressed *Make Request*.

This gives me this URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=Caroline_Wozniacki 
This contains the page with links, references and all in JSON format.

Comment: Thx, have u got an example how I can parse that ?
I prefer json than xml so I will try to make a little json parser.

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch an article like this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stackoverflow&printable=yes

or to use the API:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Stack%20Overflow&rvprop=content

this will get you the raw article code. To get the html version use `action=parse`:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=Stack_Overflow

Also have a look at the documentation: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API

Comment: Thx dude,
i want try this one http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Stack%20Overflow&rvprop=content

because I want get the infobox, u think it's hard ?

Comment: So why didn't you ask for the infobox? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10180899/956397