# How to extract Infobox from (German) Wikipedia using MediaWiki API?

Tags: python, web-scraping, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, wikidata

I want to extract the information in the Infobox from specific Wikipedia pages, mainly countries. Specifically I want to achieve this without scraping the page using `Python` + `BeautifulSoup4` or any other languages + libraries, if possible. I'd rather use the official API, because I noticed the CSS tags are different for different Wikipedia subdomains (as in other languages).

In [How to get Infobox from a Wikipedia article by Mediawiki API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638402/mediawiki-api-how-to-get-infobox-from-a-wikipedia-article) states that using the following method would work, which is indeed true for the given tital (`Scary Monsters and Nice Sprites`), but unfortunately doesn't work on the pages I tried (further below).

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xmlfm&titles=Scary%20Monsters%20and%20Nice%20Sprites&rvsection=0
```

However, I suppose `Wikimedia` changed their `infobox` template, because when I run the above query all I get is the content, but not the `infobox`. E.g. running the query on `Europäische_Union` (European_Union) results (among others) in the following snippet

```
{{Infobox Europäische Union}}
<!--{{Infobox Staat}} <- Vorlagen-Parameter liegen in [[Spezial:Permanenter Link/108232313]] -->
```

It works fine for the English version of Wikipedia though.

So the page I want to extract the infobox from would be: `http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europäische_Union`

And this is the code I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

import lxml.etree
import urllib

title = "Europäische_Union"

params = { "format":"xml", "action":"query", "prop":"revisions", "rvprop":"content", "rvsection":0 }
params["titles"] = "API|%s" % urllib.quote(title.encode("utf8"))
qs = "&".join("%s=%s" % (k, v)  for k, v in params.items())
url = "http://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?%s" % qs
tree = lxml.etree.parse(urllib.urlopen(url))
revs = tree.xpath('//rev')

print revs[-1].text
```

Am I missing something very substantial?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the Infobox data from Wikipedia?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312346/how-to-get-the-infobox-data-from-wikipedia)

Answer (score 1):

Data must not be taken from Wikipedia, but from **Wikidata** which is Wikipedia's structured data counterpart. (Also, that's not a standard infobox: it has no parameters and it's filled on [the template itself](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorlage:Infobox_Europ%C3%A4ische_Union).)

Use the Wikidata API module [wbgetclaims](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetclaims) to get all the data on the European Union:

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&entity=Q458
```

Much neater, eh? See https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Data_access for more.