# How to extract information from a Wikipedia infobox?

Tags: wikipedia, dbpedia, wikipedia-api, structured-data, wikidata

There is this fancy [infobox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Infobox) in <some Wikipedia article>. How do I get the value of <this field and that>?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the Infobox data from Wikipedia](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312346/getting-the-infobox-data-from-wikipedia)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

### The wrong way: trying to parse HTML

> Use (cURL/jQuery/file_get_contents/requests/wget/[more jQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdrW7.gif)) to fetch the HTML article code of the article, then use a DOM parser to extract `table.infobox tr[3] td` / [use a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

This is actually a really bad idea most of the time. Wikipedia's HTML code is not particularly parsing-friendly (especially infoboxes which are a system of hand-written templates), the exact structure changes from infobox to infobox, and the structure of an infobox might change over time. You might also miss out on some features that would be otherwise available, such as internationalization.

### The other wrong way: trying to parse wikitext

At a glance, the wikitext of some articles looks like it's a pretty straightforward representation of the infobox:

```
{{ Infobox Foo
| param1 = bar
| param2 = 123
...
```

In reality, that's not the case. Templates are "recursive" so you might run into stuff like `param1 = {{convert|10|km|mi}}`; template parameters might contain complex wikitext or HTML markup; some parameters might be missing from the article wikitext and fetched by the template from a subpage or other data repository. Just finding out where a parameter starts and ends might not be a simple business if it contains other templates which have their own parameters.

### The ideal way: using a structured data source

Since 2023 there is an official Wikipedia API for infobox data, still in beta, available via the [Wikimedia Enterprise](https://enterprise.wikimedia.com/) set of APIs: [API docs](https://enterprise.wikimedia.com/docs/on-demand/#article-structured-contents-beta), [announcement](https://enterprise.wikimedia.com/news/structured-contents-wikipedia-infobox/).

Other than that, there are various projects to provide the information contained in Wikipedia infoboxes in a structured form; the two large ones are Wikidata and DBpedia.

[Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/) is a project to build a knowledge base containing structured data; it is maintained by the same global movement that built Wikipedia, so information is in the process of being moved over. This is a manual process, so not all information in Wikipedia is available via Wikidata, on the other hand there is a lot of information that's in Wikidata but not in Wikipedia. You can find the Wikidata page of an article and see what information it contains by following the *Wikidata item* link in the left-hand toolbar on the article page; programmatically, you can access Wikidata information using the [wbgetentities](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities) API module ([sandbox](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=wbgetentities&format=json&sites=enwiki&props=info%7Clabels%7Cdescriptions%7Cclaims&languages=en), [explanation of concepts](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/API#General_introduction)), e.g. [wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites=enwiki&titles=Albert_Einstein](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&format=jsonfm&sites=enwiki&titles=Albert_Einstein&props=info%7Clabels%7Cdescriptions%7Cclaims&languages=en). There is also a [SPARQL endpoint](https://query.wikidata.org/), [database dumps](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Database_download), and clients in [PHP](https://github.com/addwiki/wikibase-api), [Java](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Toolkit) and [Python](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/Wikidata).

[DBPedia](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/) is a project to harvest Wikipedia infobox information by automated means and publish it in a structured form. You can find the DBPedia page for a Wikipedia article by going to `http://dbpedia.org/page/<Wikipedia article name>`, e.g. http://dbpedia.org/page/Albert_Einstein. It has many data formats, dumps, [a SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) and [various other things](http://dbpedia.org/OnlineAccess).

### The wrong ways done right

If the information you need is not available via Wikidata or DBpedia, there are still semi-structured ways of extracting data from infoboxes. For HTML-based extraction you can use Wikipedia's [REST content API](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/?doc#!/Page_content/get_page_html_title) (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/html/Albert_Einstein) which returns [a richer, more semantic HTML](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid/MediaWiki_DOM_spec) than the one used on normal article pages, and preserves in it some information about template structure.

Alternatively, you might start from wikitext and parse it into a syntax tree using the simpler, client-side [`mwparserfromhell`](https://github.com/earwig/mwparserfromhell) Python module ([docs](http://mwparserfromhell.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html)) or the more powerful [parsoid-jsapi](https://github.com/wikimedia/parsoid-jsapi) which interacts with the Wikipedia REST content service.

A higher-level Python library which tries to extract infobox contents from wikitext is [`wptools`](https://github.com/siznax/wptools).

Comment: I can use SPARQL wikidata or DBPedia? Which is better for getting Wikipedia data?

Comment: @Alex depends on your use case. DBPedia tends to be more complete; Wikidata tends to be deeper and more semantic.

Comment: I am not sure this is an ideal way tho, you'd get fewer results than parsing it yourself, even tho parsing it yourself is longer, because dpedia ok gives you date but lots of the times misses the whole date, for example on here there isn't the year on the date http://dbpedia.org/page/Victory_Tests, while the actual wikipedia page has the year too https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victory_Tests so dunno, it's longer, but a manual parsing is better

Comment: Also remember that DBPedia is not synchronized in real-time with Wikipedia, you may experience a few months delay between wikipedia version and corresponding entry in DBPedia.

Comment: I bet about half the people getting to this answer are trying to parse Wikipedia with the intention to add the data to wikidata.

Comment: I remember being really exited about DBPedia when I discovered it like 7 years ago. Unfortunately I've been disappointed almost every time I try to use it. Today I wanted to get a summary of the hydraulic head of all hydroelectric dams. Perfect usage of DBPedia. I can see that wikipedia have much of that information. But its only partially extracted: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qiaoqi_Dam https://dbpedia.org/page/Qiaoqi_Dam

In this case the information is there - right in the infobox, using what seems to be the correct key: `plant_hydraulic_head`, but it's missing from DBPedia

Answer (score 2):

There's a newer option now by the Wikimedia Foundation itself... [Wikimedia Enterprise](https://enterprise.wikimedia.com/) now has a beta that includes the parsed infobox content: https://enterprise.wikimedia.com/news/structured-contents-wikipedia-infobox/

Comment: Thanks! I added that to the canonical answer. (Feel free to edit it, it's a [wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki).)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct on all points, and especially the subtext that parsing wikitexxt is *horrible*.

If, however, getting your data from Wikidata doesn't quite work for you, because (just hypothetically) *you're the person trying to move data from WP to WD*, I believe the format you are looking for is the *parsetree*. Here is what it looks like:

```
<...lots of other stuff omitted>
<template lineStart= "1">
   <title>Datatable TableRow</title>
   <part>
      <name>Picture         </name>
      <equals>=</equals>
      <value> Picture 2013-07-26.jpg</value>
   </part>
   <part>
      <name>Inscription    </name>
      <equals>=</equals>
      <value> This is an Inscription on visible on the image</value>
   </part>
   <part>
      <name>NS           </name>
      <equals>=</equals>
      <value> 54.0902049</value>
   </part>
   <part>
      <name>EW           </name>
      <equals>=</equals>
      <value> 12.1364164</value>
   </part>
   <part>
      <name>Region       </name>
      <equals>=</equals>
      <value> DE-MV</value>
   </part>
   <part>
      <name>Name         </name>
      <equals>=</equals>
      <value> Person, Anna</value>
   </part>
   <part>
      <name>Location          </name>
      <equals>=</equals>
      <value> Lange Stra\u00dfe&amp;nbsp;14&lt;br /&gt;&lt;small&gt;ex: Lange Stra\u00dfe&amp;nbsp;89&lt;/small&gt;</value>
   </part>
   <part>
      <name>Date </name>
      <equals>=</equals>
      <value> </value>
   </part>
</template>
```

[Here's an URI](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&page=Help%3ASearching&prop=text%7Clanglinks%7Ccategories%7Clinks%7Ctemplates%7Cimages%7Cexternallinks%7Csections%7Crevid%7Cdisplaytitle%7Ciwlinks%7Cproperties%7Cparsewarnings%7Cparsetree&disablelimitreport=1&disableeditsection=1&disabletoc=1&contentformat=application%2Fjson&contentmodel=wikitext) to such a request with the Mediawiki API Sandbox. Note the list of properties that includes *parsetree*. I've included some other categories (including *categories*) just in case, and you probably want to trim the list to what you actually need, to save your time and others' servers.

Comment: The parse tree is definitely helpful but doesn't solve the issues that 1) an infobox parameter might be a template itself (unit conversion, date math, multiline formatting etc etc) 2) part of the information might come from elsewhere (e.g. city infoboxes often use demographic information stored on a different wiki page; in more horrible cases, the data is stashed into a huge Lua table) 3) the infobox might do some fairly complex manipulation of the arguments (e.g. many enwiki infoboxes generate a page description, but there isn't really a way to guess that from the raw wikitext).

Comment: Granted other methods probably won't be any better either. If you are looking for getting the most information about the infobox, the Parsoid HTML is probably the most rich, as it contains both template names and parameters and rendered HTML, but probably trickier to use.