# Parsing HTML of Wikipedia pages

Tags: html, python-2.7, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

I'd like to download all the Wikipedia pages in HTML.

Wikipedia API does an excellent job in fetching an wiki article in HTML, provided search title is mentioned.

I use the below snippet to extract a wiki article given the title:

```
title = 'Barack Obama'
ny = wikipedia.page(title)
data = urllib.urlopen(ny.url)
htmlSource = data.read()
```

The above snippet gives me the wiki page (HTML) on Barack Obama

I need the HTML file specifically because I have written some regex's to extract relevant information from the page.

I'd be glad if anybody could help me accomplish this task.

Comment: You're using the (incredibly confusingly named) [wikipedia library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikipedia/), right?

Comment: Also, you'd be much better downloading the single XML dump, instead of downloading the HTML page by page.

Comment: Ya Exactly, But as I mentioned, I have some regex that helps me parse patterns in the HTML file and retrieve relevant information. I'd be glad, if you could tell me how to get a complete HTML dump

Comment: [I believe there is no simple way to get that.](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DumpHTML#Beware.2C_cowboy.21)

Comment: What sort of "relevant information"? If you mean infobox and the like, please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33862337/1333493

Comment: [You should also not be using regexes to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1306662)