# How to get WikiQuote Source by Wikidata API?

Tags: mediawiki, wikidata-api

Which claims represent the quotes on Wikiquote? For example, for the [Knowledge](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Knowledge) page.

And the corresponding WikiData JSON: https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q9081&props=claims&languages=en&sitefilter=enwikiquote&formatversion=2

The goal is to get the source of the quote.

Comment: There is no such claim: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q9081

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Structured Wikiquote](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Structured_Wikiquote) is only a proposal. You have to parse each Wikiquote's wikitext on your own (general advice on wikitext parsing applies).

Comment: Thanks, in the intervening time, I've figured out how to get the wkitext HTML, but don't know how to parse it. What is the general advice on wikitext parsing?

Comment: @BrandonBradley http://stackoverflow.com/a/33862337/1333493 for instance (the principles are the same, details depend on which language edition you need to parse for what).