# Get contents of a list on a Wikipedia page

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'd like to return a list of the [presidents of the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States) from the wikipedia api, but I can't seem to find an efficient way to do so.

I can use the `rvsection` param to isolate to that section of the content, but it seems like a very brittle (and still hard to parse) solution. Is there an easier way to get the names of the presidents in that section?

Current query:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&pageids=19908980&rvsection=1
```

Comment: Please use Wikidata instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33862337/1333493

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular case (extracting the list of the US presidents) there's even an example [query](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23US%20presidents%20and%20spouses%0ASELECT%20%3Fp%20%3FpLabel%20%3Fppicture%20%3Fw%20%3FwLabel%20%3Fwpicture%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%09wd%3AQ30%20p%3AP6%2Fps%3AP6%20%3Fp%20.%0A%09%3Fp%20wdt%3AP26%20%3Fw%20.%0A%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fp%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fppicture%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fw%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fwpicture%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%09SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%09%09bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%09%7D%0A%7D) in wikidata query service. Although it also returns the wife of the presidents. With a little modification you can get [only presidents](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23US%20presidents%20and%20spouses%0ASELECT%20%3Fp%20%3FpLabel%20%3Fppicture%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%09wd%3AQ30%20p%3AP6%2Fps%3AP6%20%3Fp%20.%0A%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fp%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fppicture%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%09SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%09%09bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%09%7D%0A%7D)