# Getting city quick facts with Wikipedia

Tags: api, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Is it possible to get quick or interesting facts about a city using any API appropriate for this task by having available the `City`'s **name**, **country**, **latitude** and **longitude**?

For example, a query for London would return something like this:

> London, the capital of England and the United Kingdom, is a
>   21st-century city with history stretching back to Roman times. At its
>   centre stand the imposing Houses of Parliament, the iconic ‘Big Ben’
>   clock tower and Westminster Abbey, site of British monarch
>   coronations. Across the Thames River, the London Eye observation wheel
>   provides panoramic views of the South Bank cultural complex, and the
>   entire city.

Comment: You'll probably want to use Wikidata for this. Here's an example of an automated summary built from the currently available data for London: https://tools.wmflabs.org/reasonator/?&q=84

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862336/how-do-you-extract-information-from-a-wikipedia-infobox for getting facts in general. You can use [prop=coordinates](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GeoData#prop.3Dcoordinates) to match the right article to the city name in case more cities with that name exist (or do a Wikidata SPARQL query which is a bit more involved but can use geo bounding boxes).

Comment: I assume you're only interested in English descriptions? I18n/L10n of such automatic strings is very complex.