# Infobox company, website parameter autocalculated?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

Check this company infobox on Microsoft wiki page on the right hand side
at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft

Clearly it has parameter website with value as www.microsoft.com

but when I try to see its wiki source code. I dont see any reference to this key value pair. Why is that? Is it autocalculated?

After subsidiary it has directly footnote section as follows.

| subsid           = [[List of mergers and acquisitions by Microsoft|List of Microsoft subsidiaries]]
| footnotes        ={{cite web|url=http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Investor/annual-reports.aspx|title=Microsoft Corporation Annual

What am I missing here

Comment: In https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Infobox_company&action=edit you can see that it uses `{{#property:P856}}`

Comment: Thank you @Bergi . I see that now.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862336/how-do-you-extract-information-from-a-wikipedia-infobox about the generic issue of how to extract data from infoboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a Wikipedia article doesn't specify a value for the `website` (or `homepage`) parameter, the [infobox_company template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_company) will try to retrieve this data from Wikidata.

It does this by using the `{{#property}}` parser function and querying for the value of the [official website (P856)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P856) property on the Wikidata item that's linked to the article on which the infobox appears.

So, in order for this to work, an article must have a linked Wikidata item, and that item must have a value for the above property.