# Use google-api/mediawiki-api to retrieve information

Tags: java, google-api, jsoup, html-parsing, mediawiki-api

I am currently working on a University project under the theme of "search-engine".
For this purpose we were given access to a database of scientific publications
(http://dblp.uni-trier.de)

It is a 2GB XML file which looks something like this:

```
<article key="GottlobSR96">
<author>Georg Gottlob</author>
<author>Michael Schrefl</author>
<author>Brigitte R&#246;ck</author>
<title>Extending Object-Oriented Systems with Roles.</title>
<pages>268-296</pages>
<year>1996</year>
<volume>14</volume>
<journal>TOIS</journal>
<number>3</number>
<url>db/journals/tois/tois14.html#GottlobSR96</url>
</article>
```

As you can see the "article"-tag contains various information such as author,title of the paper,year of publication. My job now is to implement a Java solution which takes search terms of different categories (author, university,title) as input and provides the user with additional information.

For example if you enter the name of a professor it should return data like his date of birth, the University he works at, number of publications, etc..

I suppose this would work using google api to find for a persons entry on the University homepage and then somehow parsing through the page to find the needed information. For Universities there should be a Wikipedia page.

I already tried using mediawiki api but couldn't figure out how to get only the specific information I want.(I could only get the intro paragraph)

I've never worked on a project of this scale so I don't really have a clue on how to implement foreign API's/libraries etc. into my own code. 
So i guess my question is:

How do i get specific information based on a google-search? May it be through wikipedia or otherwise.

Comment: nobody knows an answer?

Comment: Maybe solr might be something for your project: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/ Solr offers nice features like search, facets, filters, etc.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are looking for - do you need to implement searching in this database that you have been given, or does that already work and you are just looking to enrich the results with external data?

Comment: @Tgr both needs to be done. But we split the work and I am now tasked with the enrichment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862336/how-to-extract-information-from-a-wikipedia-infobox has some relevant information. Although I'd start for looking a database (some kind of scientific publication data) where you can get reliable identifiers for the article and the authors - DOI, ORCID, something like that. Without that a search (whether Google or Wikipedia/Wikidata) is unlikely to be useful.