# Artist information with wikipedia api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wikipedia-api

Im using wikipedia api to call information from artists. The question is, how can I only call the image of the artist, name, date of birth and place, age, genres and the website. How can I only call this fields?

I have researched but I don't find anything related to wikipedia api...
I have this code:

```js
var url ="";

$("#biography").click(function() {

  $(".div-pesquisa").hide();
  $(".div-biography").show();

  url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=" + query + "&format=json&origin=*";
  url = encodeURI(url);
  
  $.get(url, function(response, status) {
    if (status == 'success') {
      $(".div-biography .row h3").html(response.parse.title);
      $(".div-biography p").html(response.parse.text['*']);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<div class="div-biography" style="overflow:scroll; height:480px;">

  <ul class="header">
    <li><button class="go-back-btn-bio" type="button" name="button" id="your-playlist"><i class="ion-ios-arrow-back"></i>GO BACK</button></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="row">
    <h3></h3>
  </div>
  <p></p>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Nelson, where is your ID `#biography` inside HTML?

Comment: Also, why is `url` assigned without `var` or `const`? Is it global?

Comment: #biography is the button, is inside another container...
Yes it is global!

Comment: *another container*... Can you please create a [mcve]?

Comment: Are you sure you want Wikipedia and not Wikidata?

Comment: on click on button "Biography" the biography of the artist appears... Just like that, But I was wondering how can I make only appear: image, name, age, place of born and date, genres and website...

https://codepen.io/nelsonpacheco15/pen/LmKNzz

Comment: Yeah Its wikipedia

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862336/how-to-extract-information-from-a-wikipedia-infobox