# How to access a table in mediawiki

Tags: python, api, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Right now I am using the mediawiki api and requests module to attempt to pull certain information from a sort of table off of a wikipedia page.  As an example, we will use the song Zombie where there is a 'table' on the right where it tells me the album, the author, the release date and so forth.  The only issue I'm running into is that I don't know how to query this data as I'm using this link as the endpoint: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&formatversion=2&action=query&titles=Zombie_(song)&prop=extracts
to attempt to search for what I need but it brings up the text on the page.  I've tried the sandbox and I've had issues trying to find what would give me the information I need.  I appreciate any advice and input, thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862336/how-to-extract-information-from-a-wikipedia-infobox

Answer (score 0):

For that sort of metadata you'd be best off using Wikidata. In the sidebar on Wikipedia there's a link to the Wikidata item, and you can use an API query such as https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&entity=Q169298 to get the data in a structured way. For information about what those results mean, see the [Wikibase API docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/API).

[*Edit:*] To get the entity ID, you can use [`wbgetentities`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/API#wbgetentities) with a Wikipedia title (`titles`) and wiki ID (`sites`); e.g.: https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites=enwiki&titles=Zombie_(song)

Comment: How would get the entity of pages that I want to query?

Comment: So, from here, how can I read through this for information from the infobox?

Comment: Check out the question that @Tgr linked to above, it's got more info.