# Fetching text from Wikipedia’s Infobox in Python

Tags: python, regex, wikipedia

want to get infobox contents of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Alg%C3%A9rie

I followed [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fetching-text-wikipedias-infobox-python/).

```
import requests 
from lxml import etree 

url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Alg%C3%A9rie'

req = requests.get(url)  

store = etree.fromstring(req.text) 

# this will give Motto portion of above  
# URL's info box of Wikipedia's page 
output = store.xpath('//table[@class="infobox vcard"]/tr[th/text()="Destinations"]/td/i')  

# printing the text portion 
print output[0].text
```

but it is null
[image]

even though req.text exists, returns null.
How can I get this infobox contents?
especially,

IATA    ICAO
AH      DAH

I need IATA, ICAO code.
please help.

Also remember that DBPedia is not synchronized in real-time with Wikipedia, you may experience a few months delay between wikipedia version and corresponding entry in DBPedia.  I don't want DBPedia contents.

Comment: first try `//table[@class="infobox vcard"]`, next `'//table[@class="infobox vcard"]/tr'` , etc. and maybe you find where is problem

Comment: `<tr>` is not directly in `<table>` so you have to use `//` between `<table>` and `<tr>` -  `//table[@class="infobox vcard"]//tr`

Comment: row with `"Destinations"` doesn't have `<i>`

Comment: to get `AH`, `DAH`, `AIR ALGERIE` you can use `xpath( '//td[@class="nickname"]' )`

Comment: `output = store.xpath('//table[@class="infobox vcard"]')`  got `[<Element table at 0x103640788>]` @furas

Comment: @furas `output = store.xpath('//table[@class="infobox vcard"]/tr')` got `[]`

Comment: as i said: in this HTML `<tr>` is not directly after `<table>` so you have to use `//` between `<table>` and `<tr>` - `'//table[@class="infobox vcard"]//tr'` - or you would have to use all tags which are between `<table>` and `<tr>` - `'//table[@class="infobox vcard"]/tbody/tr'`

Comment: your comment works! !!!!! thank you! `to get AH, DAH, AIR ALGERIE you can use xpath( '//td[@class="nickname"]' ) `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197316/discussion-between-horoyoi-o-and-furas).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract information from a Wikipedia infobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862336/how-to-extract-information-from-a-wikipedia-infobox)

Answer (score 1):

To get `AH`, `DAH`, `AIR ALGERIE` you can use

```
xpath( '//td[@class="nickname"]' )
```

---

As for your xpath: in this HTML there is `<tbody>` between `<table>` and `<tr>` so you would have to use it in xpath

```
'//table[@class="infobox vcard"]/tbody/tr[th/text()="Destinations"]/td'
```

or use `//` and it will work even if there is more tags between `<table>` and `<tr>`

```
'//table[@class="infobox vcard"]//tr[th/text()="Destinations"]/td'
```

I also skiped `<i>` at the end because row `"Destinations"` doesn't use `<i>`

---

```
import requests 
from lxml import etree 

url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Alg%C3%A9rie'

req = requests.get(url)  
store = etree.fromstring(req.text) 

output = store.xpath('//td[@class="nickname"]')  
for x in output:
    print(x.text.strip())

#output = store.xpath('//table[@class="infobox vcard"]//tr[th/text()="Destinations"]/td')
output = store.xpath('//table[@class="infobox vcard"]/tbody/tr[th/text()="Destinations"]/td')
print(output[0].text)
```

Result

```
AH
DAH
AIR ALGERIE
69
```

---

**EDIT:**

I use another xpath to get names `"IATA"`, `"ICAO"`, `"Callsign"` and then I use `zip()` to groups them with `"AH"`, `"DAH"`, `"AIR ALGERIE"`

```
import requests 
from lxml import etree 

url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Alg%C3%A9rie'

req = requests.get(url)  
store = etree.fromstring(req.text) 

keys = store.xpath('//table[@class="infobox vcard"]//table//tr[1]//a')
#for x in keys:
#    print(x.text.strip())

values = store.xpath('//td[@class="nickname"]')  
#for x in values:
#    print(x.text.strip())

some_dict = dict()

for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    k = k.text.strip()
    v = v.text.strip()
    some_dict[k] = v
    print(k, '=', v)

print(some_dict)
```

Result:

```
IATA = AH
ICAO = DAH
Callsign = AIR ALGERIE

{'IATA': 'AH', 'ICAO': 'DAH', 'Callsign': 'AIR ALGERIE'}
```

Comment: can you edit this code with `IATA ICAO Callsign` ?? I mean `AH` is `IATA` code.

Comment: then do `some_dict["IATA"] = output[0].text`

Comment: no. what i mean, I cannot get "IATA" from store.xpath

Comment: I don't get "IATA" from xpath. I use directly string "IATA" . Why to use xpath for string which I already know ?

Comment: but sometimes pages may have different names - some names can be skiped on page - and then it is good to use xpath to get them. I added example which gets strings "IATA", "ICAO", "Callsign" from page and groups them with "AH", "DAH", "AIR ALGERIE"