# Wikipedia API - Retrieve USA Power Plants by Date Built

Tags: wikipedia-api

I'm racking my brain how to use the Wikipedia API to get a list of the power plants in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Coal-fired_power_stations_in_the_United_States_by_state

Then include the data from the Commission Date field next to each plant.  (Alternatively, cross-reference with the "energy infrastructure completed in 19XX" category)

Where do I start?  EIA this information, but only for the actual generators that are still in use, not the date for the powerplants housing those generators.  I also found some Data related to Co2 production, but those dates go back only to 1945.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862336/how-to-extract-information-from-a-wikipedia-infobox. Use DBPedia (same dataset as Wikipedia) or Wikidata (not necessarily the same, might be better or worse) and do a SPARQL query.